# product rule constants

Tags: derivatives, constants

I'm struggling with the concept of constants in the context of derivatives.
For example;

$$f(\theta)=r(\cos\theta-1)$$ where $r$ is a constant.
$$f'(\theta)=-r\sin\theta$$

Why is the product rule not used in the above?

Comment: @TheSimp  I was speaking to your claim about the RHS of  the derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $\theta + 1$.  I was simply saying that we have that we are taking the derivative of $r(\cos(\theta)-1),$ and not of $r(\cos(\theta-1))$, so that we are not, afterall, taking the

Comment: I can't seem to edit it, but yes I see my mistake now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still apply the product rule in the following way:
$$ f'(x)= \frac {dr}{dx}(cos\theta-1)+r \frac{d(cos\theta-1)}{dx} = 0(cos\theta-1)+r(-sin\theta+0)=-rsin\theta  $$

Since we have the following differentiation rule (which is a direct corollary of the product rule):

$$ \frac{d(kf(x))}{dx} = k\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$ where $k$ is a constant,

we usually do not use the product rule in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the product rule (if you like). Just need to note that the derivative of a constant ($r$ here) is $0$, and you will get the same result.

Comment: right... That's the thing I missed.  I tried working it out using the product rule.  I just missed what you mentioned above.